# PHP not detected by Vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Vscode does not detect my php.

I have installed :

PHP 8.2.6 (cli) (built: May 11 2023 12:51:38) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.2.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

And i also installed PHP Debug on vscode but it still not work.

Installed PHP Debug
Installed PHP IntelliSense
Checked echo $PATH

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, downloaded php with homebrew

1. open terminal and type: which php
2. copy: /opt/homebrew/bin/php
3. open vscode and open settings with command+, and search for php.executablePath
4. add these two lines :
   "php.executablePath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/php",
   "php.validate.executablePath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/php"

Save and restart vscode.

Comment: It would be great if you provide Screen Shots.